# Micro vs weighted F1 score

Tags: classification, metric, multi-class, multilabel

In a multi-label or multi-class classification setting, when choosing between a micro or a weighted F1 score, what shall I take into account?

The main upside of choosing macro is that one gets a sense of effectiveness on small classes. Assuming that the small classes are of no importance, how to choose between micro or a weighted F1 score?

Answer (score 0):

Micro f1 is based on global precision and recall. It treats each test case equally and doesn't give advantages to small classes. I think it's more suitable.

[This article "Macro- and micro-averaged evaluation measures" from Vincent Van Asch in U of Antwerp](https://web.archive.org/web/20190130054158/https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1d10/6a2730801b6210a67f7622e4d192bb309303.pdf) explains many different kinds of f1 scores.